# need to export individual features to shapefiles using geopandas

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, geojson, geopandas

I'm using geopandas to read a geojson file and output shapefiles. The issue is I cannot figure out how to export single features within that shapefile - only the entire shapefile. Just for ref, I'm using google colab.

here's what I have so far

```
os.makedirs('/content/drive/MyDrive/shapes')
gdf = gpd.read_file('/content/sample_data/countries.geojson')
for num, row in gdf.iterrows():
    key = row.city
    fileName = key+".shp"
    path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/shapes/'+fileName
    os.makedirs('/content/drive/MyDrive/shapes/'+fileName)
    os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/shapes/'+fileName)
    gdf.to_file(fileName) # need to do something like row to file here
```

this code will export a bunch of shapefiles of the original geojson file & name them by a certain key. I can't figure out how to loop through the individual features and make a shapefile for each.

Comment: So you want to loop over a column of the shapefile and extract each row and save it into a new shapefil, am I right?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to loop over each feature in a geojson file and save each feature to a shapefile

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't have your shapefile, I am going to answer your question based on what you have told in your question. First of all, you should not save the `gdf` dataframe every time because you want to save the row into a file(I think each row represents a city and you want to have this city in a different shapefile that is named after the city name). So, what I suggest is:

```
os.makedirs('/content/drive/MyDrive/shapes')
gdf = gpd.read_file('/content/sample_data/countries.geojson')
for num, row in gdf.iterrows():
    key = row.city
    fileName = key+".shp"
    path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/shapes/'+fileName
    os.makedirs(path)
    os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/shapes/'+fileName)
    gdf.iloc[num:num+1,:].to_file(path)
```

Note that, instead of saving in `filename` I saved the file into `path` because if it wasn't the case, the last few lines in your code would be for nothing!